# OSGI-Karaf-REST API

Tags: apache-karaf, business-process-management, camunda

I am following [the camunda guide on github](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform-osgi) and successfully able to start my Process_1 by using `@PostDeploy` method in my `ExampleProcessApplication` class.

Now I want to use a REST API in the karaf environment so that I can start a process when I get some external triggering.

I installed `camunda-bpm-karaf-feature-minimal` by following [the github helper](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform-osgi/tree/master/camunda-bpm-karaf-feature).

I am not able to call `feature:install camunda-bpm-karaf-feature-full` (I am using Apache karaf 3.0.7) error msg is as follows:

```
Missing requirements osgi.wiring.package=javax.transaction
```

I couldn't find how to install `version 1.3`.

Do I need to install any other bundle to use a REST API in karaf environment?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that they changed their javax.transaction api from com.springsource.javax.transaction to javax.transaction-api when they changed from 1.3 to 2.0. I recommend you to use their 2.0 version feature.